# iPad app in store crashing, trouble working out TestFlight logs

Tags: ios, crash-reports, crash-dumps, testflight, symbolicatecrash

So I'm getting many crash logs for my app showing up in TestFlight on a live app (iPad 5.0+ only)

**2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x332a9e92 _sigtramp + 42**

**3 UIKit 0x34b97372 + 226...**

**Exception Reason: SIGSEGV**

Here is all the threads from the TestFlight log...

```
    0 MyApp 0x00214aaa testflight_backtrace + 158
1 MyApp 0x002156d4 TFSignalHandler + 244
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x332a9e92 _sigtramp + 42
3 UIKit 0x34b97372 <redacted> + 226
4 UIKit 0x34bbe4e4 <redacted> + 88
5 CoreFoundation 0x355b2036 _CFXNotificationPost + 1426
6 Foundation 0x386a5d90 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
7 Foundation 0x386a9852 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 30
8 UIKit 0x34bbb656 <redacted> + 2182
9 UIKit 0x34b311e6 <redacted> + 2458
10 UIKit 0x34b306cc <redacted> + 72
11 UIKit 0x34b3011a <redacted> + 6154
12 GraphicsServices 0x32efb5a2 _PurpleEventCallback + 590
13 GraphicsServices 0x32efb1d2 PurpleEventCallback + 34
14 CoreFoundation 0x35636172 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
15 CoreFoundation 0x35636116 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 138
16 CoreFoundation 0x35634f98 __CFRunLoopRun + 1384
17 CoreFoundation 0x355a7ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
18 CoreFoundation 0x355a7d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
19 GraphicsServices 0x32efa2ea GSEventRunModal + 74
20 UIKit 0x34b842f8 UIApplicationMain + 1120
21 MyApp 0x001cf4dc _ZN17ofAppiPhoneWindow20startAppWithDelegateESs + 168
22 MyApp 0x001cf364 _ZN17ofAppiPhoneWindow21runAppViaInfiniteLoopEP9ofBaseApp + 200
23 MyApp 0x001dd7ce _Z8ofRunAppP9ofBaseApp + 422
24 MyApp 0x000027aa main (main.mm:13)
25 MyApp 0x0000271b start + 39

com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0 CoreFoundation 0x35634da2 __CFRunLoopRun + 882
1 CoreFoundation 0x355a7ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
2 CoreFoundation 0x355a7d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
3 Foundation 0x386d1bcc +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 308
4 Foundation 0x3875567c __NSThread__main__ + 972
5 libsystem_c.dylib 0x33282310 _pthread_start + 308
6 libsystem_c.dylib 0x332821d7 thread_start + 7

com.apple.coremedia.player.async
0 CoreMedia 0x3235b9a8 FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 260
1 MediaToolbox 0x33fbd35a <redacted> + 26
2 CoreMedia 0x3237998a <redacted> + 194
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x33282310 _pthread_start + 308
4 libsystem_c.dylib 0x332821d7 thread_start + 7

AURemoteIO::IOThread
0 AudioToolbox 0x32812990 _ZN10AURemoteIO8IOThread5EntryEPv + 8
1 AudioToolbox 0x327508a4 _ZN9CAPThread5EntryEPS_ + 296
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x33282310 _pthread_start + 308
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x332821d7 thread_start + 7

Thread 11
0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x332778a3 start_wqthread + 7

Thread 14
0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x332778a3 start_wqthread + 7

WebThread
0 CoreFoundation 0x35634da2 __CFRunLoopRun + 882
1 CoreFoundation 0x355a7ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
2 CoreFoundation 0x355a7d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
3 WebCore 0x35ca2a44 <redacted> + 444
4 libsystem_c.dylib 0x33282310 _pthread_start + 308
5 libsystem_c.dylib 0x332821d7 thread_start + 7

Thread 8
0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x332778a3 start_wqthread + 7

com.apple.CFSocket.private
0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x332821d7 thread_start + 7

com.apple.coremedia.player.remote
0 CoreMedia 0x3237998a <redacted> + 194
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x33282310 _pthread_start + 308
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x332821d7 thread_start + 7

Thread 1
0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x332778a3 start_wqthread + 7

Thread 2
0 0xffffffff 0xffffffff

Thread 3
0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x332778a3 start_wqthread + 7

Thread 6
0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x332778a3 start_wqthread + 7

Thread 7
0 CoreFoundation 0x35634da2 __CFRunLoopRun + 882
1 CoreFoundation 0x355a7ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
2 CoreFoundation 0x355a7d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
3 Foundation 0x386a878e -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 254
4 Foundation 0x3874c05c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 80
5 MyApp 0x0022a578 -[TFNetworkManager networkRunLoopThreadEntry] + 124
6 Foundation 0x3875567c __NSThread__main__ + 972
7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x33282310 _pthread_start + 308
8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x332821d7 thread_start + 7

Load Address
0x00001000

Register Values

cpsr: 48
exception: 0
far: 3758096392
fsr: 5
lr: 884568947
pc: 975418800
r0: 25362176
r1: 888934373
r10: 0
r11: 8398466
r12: 994475364
r2: 25175555
r3: 3
r4: 3758096384
r5: 3
r6: 148
r7: 803202360
r8: 2
r9: 222233593
sp: 803202292
```

I can't work out why it might be crashing. Something to do NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName?

If you have any ideas they would be very much appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: are you or any library in your app using `NSNotificationCenter`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to unsubscribe from notifications every time when view is deallocated.